# Group an array based on it's key and create a new array with group as it's index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a new array from an array which will be group by the key and the new array's index will be the old array's key, something like this

### Old array

```
Array1
0 :term_id: "1"
   capacity:"11"
   price: "452"
1 :term_id: "2"
   capacity:"33"
   price: "44"
2 :term_id: "1"
   capacity:"1"
   price: "2"
```

I am looking to group this array by `term_id` so the new array is

### New array

```
Array2
1 :terms >
   0: capacity:"11"
      price: "452"
   1: capacity:"1"
      price: "2"
2 :terms >
  0:  capacity:"33"
      price: "44"
```

As you can see, in the new array the array is grouped by index of term_id and there is another arary inside with its contents

I tried using `groupBy` method, but I am unable to preserve the index of old array

Comment: Please share the actual input and output arrays, along with your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and build the desired output.

```js
var Array1 = [{  term_id: "1",  capacity: "11",  price: "452"}, {  term_id: "2",  capacity: "33",  price: "44"}, {  term_id: "1",  capacity: "1",  price: "2"}];

var result = Object.values(Array1.reduce((a, {term_id, capacity, price}) => {
  (a[term_id] || (a[term_id] = {terms: []})).terms.push({capacity, price});
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your object array based on `term_id` in an object, then get all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [{ term_id: "1", capacity: "11", price: "452" }, { term_id: "2", capacity: "33", price: "44" }, { term_id: "1", capacity: "1", price: "2" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{term_id, capacity, price})=> {
      r[term_id] = r[term_id] || [];
      r[term_id].push({capacity, price});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There are lots of array elements beside `capacity, price` is there a way to push all those elements without having to specify each one?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` of Array.prototype

```js
x = [{term_id:"1",capacity:"11",price:"452"},{term_id:"2",capacity:"33",price:"44"},{term_id:"1",capacity:"1",price:"2"}];

y = x.reduce((n, e) => {
            var clone = Object.assign({}, e);  //creating duplicate object
            delete clone.term_id;              //deleteing term_id property from clone object
            if (!n[e.term_id]) {
                n[e.term_id] = [];
            }
            n[e.term_id].push(clone);    //pushing clone instead of e as e contains term_id which we don't need in result
            return n;
        }, {});
   
console.log(y);
```

Comment: There are lots of array elements beside capacity, price is there a way to push all those elements without having to specify each one?

Comment: push e instead of a new hash.

Comment: @zuif edited the answer as per your requirement mention in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hashtable for grouping:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const obj of array) {
   if(hash[obj.term_id]) {
     hash[obj.term_id].push(obj);
   } else {
     result.push(hash[obj.term_id] = [obj]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to use a loop... It's kinda a waste of memory to copy all the data into the result, I think it's a better practice to generate the data you need and keep any values that already exist in place, but that might lead to uglier code down the line so -_-

```js
function idxOfGroupBy(hl,key){
let ret = [];
for(var k = 0; k < hl.length; k++){
 try{
  ret[hl[k][key]].push(k);
 }catch(err){
  ret[hl[k][key]] = [];
  ret[hl[k][key]].push(k);
 }
}
return(ret);
}

let hashList = [{at1:"1",atr2:"."},{at1:"2",atr2:".."},{at1:"1",atr2:"..."}];
let groupIdxs = idxOfGroupBy(hashList,"at1");
console.log(groupIdxs);
```